# Выборка адресов при полнотекстовом поиске

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных, mariadb, полнотекстовый-поиск

Есть база адресов с полнотекстовым полем.

В поле значения типа:

```
Кировский р-н., Мира ул., 44б
Кировский р-н., Мира ул., 40а
Кировский р-н., Мира ул., 44а
Кировский р-н., Мира ул., 42
```

Для поиска адресов строится запрос

```
SELECT `id`, `street_id`, `object_id`, `search_string` FROM `addr_houses` WHERE MATCH(search_string) AGAINST("+мира +4*" IN BOOLEAN MODE) LIMIT 10
```

Проблема в том, что этот запрос не ищет адреса, у которых слово короче 3-х букв,
например вышеописанный запрос не выберет адрес

```
Кировский р-н., Мира ул., 42
```

Также не получается выгрести адреса с запросом "8 марта", а вот по "марта" - ищет.

ОС: Windows 10, СУБД - MariaDB 10.1, Движок таблиц InnoDB.

Подсказали, что дело в установленной минимальной длине слова, посмотрел так:
`SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'ft_min_word_len'`

Значение равно 4.

Изменил в конфиге на 1, перезапустил службу, запрос стал показывать значение 1.
Теперь надо обновить полнотекстовый индекс.
Нашел в интернете 2 варианта:

```
1. REPAIR TABLE table_name QUICK;
2. OPTIMIZE TABLE table_name;
```

1. показал `The storage engine for the table doesn't support repair`
2. подумал подумал и показал 2 сообщения `Table does not support optimize, doing recreate + analyze instead` и status=`OK`

Но после этих действий поиск все еще не выбирает строки со словами короче 3-х букв.

Поправка: Запрос типа "мира" найдет строку с домом 42, но "мира 4" не ищет, поэтому я не знаю как точно сформулировать проблему, надеюсь на понимание.

UPD 1:

Попробовал DROP, ADD

```
ALTER TABLE addr_houses DROP INDEX `FULLTEXT_addr_houses_search_string`;

ALTER TABLE addr_houses ADD FULLTEXT INDEX `FULLTEXT_addr_houses_search_string` (`search_string`);
```

Чтобы убедиться, что используется этот индекс после удаления сделал запрос, на что получил ошибку типа "cant find fulltext index"
После добавления индекса выборка работает по старому - как описано выше.

Comment: `DROP INDEX` / `CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX`

Comment: @Akina, Попробовал, не вышло =( Добавил подробности в пост

Comment: После удаления и попытки создания индекса сервер утверждает, что индекса нет. Думаю, он не врёт. Тогда куда Вы смотрели, когда давали команду создания индекса? Что сообщил сервер? какая была ошибка? какое предупреждение? не надо зажмуриваться, скорее наоборот...

Comment: @Akina, ошибка была когда я его удалил, когда я его создал все стало по старому

Comment: То есть сейчас имеется ПТ-индекс, созданный при `ft_min_word_len=1`, текущее значение такое же, искомые односимвольные "слова" не входят в стоп-лист, но всё равно не ищутся?

Comment: @Akina, Да, сейчас проверил еще раз ft_min_word_len=1. Что такое стоп лист? фильтра после поиска нет, смотрю ровно то что вернул запрос. Строки со словами короче 3-х символов ищутся, если в запросе их не было, то есть если запросить "мира 4", то "мира 42" не найдется, а если запросить просто "мира", то найдется

Comment: *Что такое стоп лист?* https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-stopwords.html